# Unwanted "gap" on the side of my website

Tags: html, css

And for some reason the gap is noticeable only with to footer and the header. I don't want to add a `min-width: 1050px` thing because that would be breaking the whole idea of my website.

You can check it for yourself [here](http://m.psichologique.com).

Disclaimer: I don't win anything from the ad, that's my host. (I really need to change)

Also, I already tried to add `margin:0px` to the body. It didn't work.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @wavemode Chrome. If you don't notice it, scroll to the right.

Comment: Fix your HTML errors first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fm.psichologique.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Adding `margin: 0px;` to `body` keeps the horizontal scroll bar. If I don't add that the horizontal scroll is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `div.nav{margin-right:-8px}` and also
add this **`body{margin:0px}`** in your css.

This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin from `.nav`

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i can't recommend the margin-left or margin-right in pixel in a liquid site, you must use it in percentage.

your site scrolling due you hard coded margin. 
first you remove that by replacing

```
div.nav {
    background-color: #FF5A5A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
    min-height: 6%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I use pixels just because it's a negative value. I also use them because I don't know how else to remove the default margin around the header/nav. I self learned most of CSS so that's why I do it my way.

Answer (score 0):

remove div.nav

```
margin-left:-8px;
margin-right:-8px;
```

and make sure to add margin:0px for body definition

```
body{margin:0px}
```

for safety reason add this definition for image tags

```
img{border:0px}
```